# Override default Spring-Boot application.properties with application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

Want to completely replace my application.properties with `application-test.properties` for my junit.
`TestPropertySource` is not doing the job. Seems like it only replaces some of the common properties but i dont want that.

Want to load `application-test.properties` not `application.properties` in my Junit \ integraction test.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles( "test" )
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application-test.properties")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
```

Comment: Don't run it as `@SpringBootTest` instead construct your own spring configured test.

Comment: but still i got this worked with just `@ActiveProfiles( "test" )`

Answer (score 0):

There is a property to that annotation that would suppress inheritance of properties:

```
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application-test.properties", inheritProperties=false)
```

The default is `true` so you need to set that explicitly.

As per documentation:

> If inheritProperties is set to false, the inlined properties for the
>   test class will shadow and effectively replace any inlined properties
>   defined by a superclass.

Answer (score 0):

I normally have a resources folder in my test folder (src/test/resources) where i place a modified application.properties and spring-boot should take this. See on https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring 5.3